# PowerShell IF Matches

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to apply NTFS folder permissions using PowerShell, there are different sec groups for each of the folders. What i'm looking to do is to be able to say IF security group matches folder name which contains add permissions. Below is the code I have currently, just doing the foreach loop works but adds the sec groups to each of the folders which isn't what I want.

```
$folderpath = $datafromcsv.contentpath
foreach ($folder in $folderpath) {
    if ($GroupName.StartsWith(DATA-$row.FolderName){
        $dfsnfolder = Get-Acl -path $folder.Contains($row.FolderName)
        $applysecgrouppermissions = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Russells.com\$GroupName","ReadData","ContainerInherit","None","Allow")
        $dfsnfolder.SetAccessRule($applysecgrouppermissions)
        $dfsnfolder | Set-Acl $folder
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, hello to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as for how to ask a question. This code does not allow to replicate the problem.
Based on the code itself, if you are iterating through the folders and setting ACLs on the folder, then folder ACL you will have. :)

Comment: Hi,Okay so I'm creating new acls named to match the folder name - what I would like to know is how to match the folder name and the ACL name to each other so the specific ACLs are only added to the folder which contains the same name as the ACL?

Comment: Without quoting, the `StartsWith()` method wouldn't have any valid string to match. Not ony that, but you forgot a closing bracket in your `if()`. What is `$row` and where does it come from?. Keep in mind also that `StartsWith()` is case-sensitive, so I would recommend using the `-like` operator on the combined groupname followed by a wildcard `*`.

Comment: Thanks Theo, great advice. Okay the $row is an import from my .CSV file containing the DFSR info (group names, content paths, folder names etc).  Could you give an example of how you are explaining to use the StartsWith() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it if I understood everything correctly.

```
     foreach ($folder in $datafromcsv) {
          $dfsnfolder = Get-Acl -path $folder.contentpath
          $filter = $GroupName | ? {$_ -like "$($folder.FolderName)*"}  // I'm assuming $GroupName contains an array with all the AD group names.
          foreach ($g in $filter) {
     
               $applysecgrouppermissions = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Russells.com\$g","ReadData","ContainerInherit","None","Allow")
               $dfsnfolder.SetAccessRule($applysecgrouppermissions)
               $dfsnfolder | Set-Acl $folder.contentpath
          }
     }
```

Comment: Alex, this is perfect, thank you very much... The question mark is what was needed to be used then to allow to match the sec group to the folder name. This is working quite well now. I'll be looking to integrate in the try/ catch commands on applying the permissions now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad to have helped. Remember to upvote and verify the answer. :)